# Stop google from indexing member(that have set their profile as private) profiles

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best practice for allowing members on my site to opt out of being indexed by google.

I have a sitemap-index with custom sitemaps for each module (members , forums , blogs etc)

The member sitemap is generated from the DB with php.

I am assuming I will have to add another column to the member table, "opt_out" which will be set to "on" when a member selects to keep their profiles private.

How would I proceed from there, can I just exclude them from the member-sitemap.php with a WHERE clause ( like "WHERE `member`.`opt_out` != 'on' ) or would I need to create a robot.txt file or a "no-follow" tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `noindex` on the user's profile page:

```
<?php if($user_settings['search_index_opt_out']){ ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will do this. I would still have to exclude them from the members-sitemap though, right?

Comment: @maximl337 Even if they are listed on the members-sitemap, Google won't index the profile if the above meta tag is present.